# Azure Service Fabric Publish Error: Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.UnregisterApplicationType

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure, publish, azure-service-fabric

I found the lonely part of Google today when I came across this error.  Not sure what has changed as it worked just yesterday, but now when I try to publish to my Service Fabric from Visual Studio 2015, I get this error:

```
3>Application Type  MyApp  and Version  1.0.0  was already registered with Cluster, unregistering it...
3>Unregister-ServiceFabricApplicationType : Application type and version is still in use
3>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
3>Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-UpgradedServiceFabricApplication.ps1:185 char:20
3>+             $reg | Unregister-ServiceFabricApplicationType -Force
3>+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [Unregister-Serv 
3>   iceFabricApplicationType], FabricException
3>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnregisterApplicationTypeErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.UnregisterApplicatio 
3>   nType
3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to upgrade an app with app type MyApp and version 1.0.0 but there already exists an app in the cluster with that same app type and version.  Therefore, this error occurs because in order to register the new app type that you're deploying, it has to unregister the conflicting app type.  But it can't unregister it because there's an existing app using it.

You may have run into this issue because you're attempting to upgrade an app without actually changing its version.